# compact(): Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

hi i have a laravel applcation that works properly on local but not working on server and here is the part and the error it throws :

```
compact(): Undefined variable: 00558852 // the number is what user have inserted
```

and here is the code :

```
 public function sendSms(Request $request)
    {
        $cellphone = $request->mobile;

        //        sending sms
        $token = rand('11111', '99999');
        $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
        $key = '4C77664C384B376F6A59376A3737496F31533954556D717353574A416249314A376B4E4C4B7A4A466C70343D';
        $result = $client->post('https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/' . $key . '/verify/lookup.json
', [
            'form_params' => [
                'receptor' => $request->mobile,
                'token' => $token,
                'template' => 'Register',
            ]
        ]);
        $temp = Temp::where('cellphone', $request->mobile);
        if ($temp) {
            $temp->delete();
        }
        $created = Temp::create([
            'cellphone' => $request->mobile,
            'code' => $token,
        ]);
        return view('shop::customers.signup.verify-sms', compact('cellphone', $cellphone));
```

first i thought it would be because of php version i downgraded to 7.2 but it yet throws the same error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `compact('cellphone')` instead. For example:

```
return view('shop::customers.signup.verify-sms', compact('cellphone'));
```